# Running another instance of bitcoin-qt dedicated to testnet/regtest?

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, regtest, bitcoin-qt-setup

Is it possible to run another instance of `bitcoin-qt` dedicated to testnet/regtest? If so, how do i do this?

My question is similar to "[Running two bitcoind instances for different nets](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2052/running-two-bitcoind-instances-for-different-nets%22)," but I want to associate `bitcoin-qt`, not just `bitcoind`, with the testnet/regtest.

Comment: +1 for researching and clarifying how your question is different than a similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your OS you can start a 2nd bitcoin-qt acting on a non-mainnet with `./bitcoin-qt -testnet` or `./bitcoin-qt -regtest` (from a shell). You can also define a custom datadir and place a bitcoin.conf there (use `bitcoin-qt -datadir=<path>`).

On OSX/Mac you would need to use Terminal and run something like `/Applications/Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt -regtest`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it was that easy! thank you! The `datadir` flag was just what I was looking for, too, although don't testnet/regtest have their own dedicated directories anyways? (At least regtest does, according to the [Bitcoin Developer Examples documentation](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode): "Regtest wallets and block chain state (chainstate) are saved in the regtest subdirectory of the Bitcoin Core configuration directory.")

Comment: I just ran `bitcoin-qt -regtest`, and it launched with a green icon, distinguishing it from my already-running red one! Nice!

Comment: Right. Testnet and regtest has their own subdirectories. But not for the bitcoin.conf. So if you'd like to set `-regtest` (or similar) within the config and only set `-datadir` while executing the binary, this would require different data directories (which is always a good idea if you run multiple nodes).